# use persian character in query string with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, url-encoding

in query string have persian character but url like this :

```
localhost:53297/#/Item/News/1-1-1-3?title=%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%86%D9%85%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C%20%D8%A7%D8%B2%20%D8%AA%D8%A8%D9%84%D8%AA%20%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C%20%D8%B4%D8%B1%DA%A9%D8%AA%20HP
```

I want url like this:

```
localhost:53297/#/Item/News/1-1-1-3?title=طلا-نقره
```

Comment: try using `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: tanx I tried but not help me. it was code my url i need decode my url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using `decodeURIComponent(yourUrl)`

and globally you can use something like this

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (e, newUrl, oldUrl) {
    $location.$$absUrl = decodeURIComponent(newUrl);
});
```

Comment: I used it for a while but it does'nt work anymore ! :|  any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use following package:
https://github.com/usablica/persian.js

Answer (score 0):

I fixed answers:

```
var newUrl = persianJs(searchQuery).fixURL().toString();

$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (e, newUrl, oldUrl) {
    $location.$$absUrl = decodeURIComponent(newUrl);
});
```